# How can I mix between a ssr component and a client component in Nextjs 13?

Tags: next.js

The point is to implement a **dynamic SSR component** can be **re-rendered** by a **search input**.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a layout.tsx file on my specific router then import children which made me dynamic render ssr component by the client component:

**Layout.tsx**

```js
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import Search from "./Search";
export default function RootLayout({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
    return (
        <div className="layout">
            <Search />
            {children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Search.tsx**

```js
"use client";
import { FormEvent, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function Search() {
    const [text, setText] = useState<string>("")
    const router: any = useRouter();

    const handleSubmit = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setText('')
        router.push(`/definition/${text}`)
    }
   
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='search'>
            <input onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
                value={text} type="text"
                placeholder={"write to search"} />    
        </form>
    );
}   );
}
```